# the 'for' loop must implement 'Iterable<dynamic>' on a Future function

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to return a map but the way I'm trying to iterate over the list but the way I am integrating over it is causing a problem.

I'm getting this error
Error:
The type 'Future<List> Function()' used in the 'for' loop must implement 'Iterable'.

```
///Model Event  
class Event {
  final int id;
  final bool free;
  final String epoch;
  final String address;
  final bool all_day;
  final String end_date;
  final String description;
  final String start_date;

  Event(
    this.id,
    this.free,
    this.epoch,
    this.address,
    this.all_day,
    this.end_date,
    this.description,
    this.start_date,
  );

  @override
  String toString() =>
      "$id, $free, $epoch, $address, $all_day, $end_day, $description, $start_date";
}
```

This returns a List<event>

```
///Future to get information from the API
Future<List<Event>> eventList() async {
  var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(Constants.EVENTS_API));
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var jsonData = json.decode(response.body);
    //print(jsonData);

    List<Event> allEvents = [];

    for (var map in jsonData) {
      Event events = Event(
        map["id"],
        map["free"],
        map["epoch"],
        map["address"],
        map["all_day"],
        map["end_date"],
        map['description'],
        map["start_date"],
      );
      allEvents.add(events);
    }
    return allEvents;
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load');
  }
}
```

I then try to add it to a new Map

```
mydates() {
  var eventDayMap = <DateTime, List<Event>>{};

  for (var event in eventList()) {
    (eventDayMap[DateTime.parse(event.start_date)] ??= []).add(event);
  }
  return eventDayMap;
}
```

the mydates function is called from here

```
final kEvents = LinkedHashMap<DateTime, List<Event>>(
  equals: isSameDay,
  hashCode: getHashCode,
)..addAll(mydates());
```

Here is the function receiving the kEvents

```
List<Event> _getEventsForDay(DateTime day) {
  

    return kEvents[day] ?? [];
  }
```

What have I got to do to implement a 'Iterable<dynamic>', iterables like values or keys won't work.

Thanks

Comment: we still need to know where you call the `_getEventsForDay` function. Can you please share the entire widget code and remove what you think is not relevant?

Answer (score 2):

Your `eventList()` function returns a Future that returns a list, so you can't use it directly in your for loop. Try changing your `mydates()` like so:

```dart
Future<Map<DateTime, List<Event>>> mydates() async {
  var eventDayMap = <DateTime, List<Event>>{};

  List<Event> _allEvents = await eventList();
  for (var event in _allEvents) {
    (eventDayMap[DateTime.parse(event.start_date)] ??= []).add(event);
  }
  return eventDayMap;
}
```

OR:

```dart
Future<Map<DateTime, List<Event>>> mydates() async {
  var eventDayMap = <DateTime, List<Event>>{};

  for (var event in await eventList()) {
    (eventDayMap[DateTime.parse(event.start_date)] ??= []).add(event);
  }
  return eventDayMap;
}
```

---

UPDATE:
Where you are calling your `mydates()` function, you need to `await` it

```dart
Map<DateTime, List<Event>> _myDates = await mydates();
final kEvents = LinkedHashMap<DateTime, List<Event>>(
  equals: isSameDay,
  hashCode: getHashCode,
)..addAll(_myDates);
```

OR

```dart
late LinkedHashMap<DateTime, List<Event>> kEvents;
mydates().then((_myDates) {
  if(_myDates != null) {
    kEvents = LinkedHashMap<DateTime, List<Event>>(
      equals: isSameDay,
      hashCode: getHashCode,
    )..addAll(_myDates);
  }
});
```

I also added return types to the functions above as suggested by the comment

---

Comment: Thanks for your help, it has to return a 'Map<DateTime, List<Event>>'  but now it's  returning a type 'Future<dynamic>'

Comment: Can you show me the code where you are calling the `mydates()` function?

Comment: I've added it now to the question.

Comment: As a general advice, it is best not to omit the return type in your functions, since it will default to `dynamic` or (Future<dynamic> for async functions), which in most cases is not very helpful. In this case I strongly suggest explicitly declaring the return type as `Future<Map<DateTime, List<Event>>>`.

Comment: Because the `mydates()` function is now async as well you have to await the result of calling `mydates()` in order to get back the `Map<DateTime, List<Event>>`.

Comment: @johnnyq see the updated answer

Comment: Thanks again the super is causing an issue Error: Expected identifier, but got 'super'. When I removed it then it won't initialize the KEvents

Comment: I need to see the widget code to understand this error.

Comment: It's being called by a function I have added, it needs the Datetime first and then the event. With your extra solution the kEvents isn't then initialized when imported. thanks again for your help.

Comment: You're very welcome. Thanks for updating the question, but we still need to know where you call the `_getEventsForDay` function. Can you please share the entire widget code and remove what you think is not relevant?

Comment: Here is the file where _getEventsForDay is, it's part of the table_calendar plugin for flutter https://github.com/aleksanderwozniak/table_calendar/blob/master/example/lib/pages/events_example.dart

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240872/discussion-between-roaa-and-johnnyq).